# Broken link on uploaded file

Tags: parse-platform

There are numerous posts regarding this issue but none have helped me. Error codes aren't helping.

Here's my server side code - I'm using Node + Express and uploading the file to Parse on the server-side:

```
exports.changeProfilePicture = function(req, res) {

console.log("exports.changeProfilePicture -- start");

var sessionToken = req.session.sessionToken;

Parse.User.become(sessionToken).then(function (user) {

    // var fstream;
    req.pipe(req.busboy);
    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {

        var parseFile = new Parse.File(filename, {base64: file.toString('base64', 0, file.length)}); // Convert from buffer object to array

        console.log("parseFile");
        console.log(parseFile);

        parseFile.save().then(function(file) {

            console.log("file.url = " + file.url);
            console.log(file);

            user.set('profilePictureMedium', file);
            user.save().then(function() {

                    console.log("exports.changeProfilePicture -- 200");

                    // res.send({status:200});
                    res.status(200).send();
                }, function(error) {

                    console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);

                    res.status(503).send({ errorCode: error.code, errorMessage:  error.message});
            });

        }, 
        function(error) {
            // The file either could not be read, or could not be saved to Parse.
            console.log("parseFile.save() -- Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);

            res.status(503).send({ errorCode: error.code, errorMessage:  error.message});

        });
    });
}, function (error) {
  // The token could not be validated.
  console.log("exports.logout -- become -- error = " + error);
  res.status(503).send();

});
```

Here's client-side AJAX:

```
     var fileUploadControl = $(".image-preview-input input:file")[0];  

  if (fileUploadControl.files.length > 0) {

      var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];

      var formdata = new FormData();
      formdata.append("file", file);
      formdata.append("coords", JSON.stringify(coordInfo));

      $.ajax({
          url: '/changeProfilePicture',
          type: 'post',
          xhr: function() {  // custom xhr
              myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
              if(myXhr.upload){ // check if upload property exists

                  // for handling the progress of the upload
                  myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false); 
              }
              return myXhr;
          },
          success: function(data) {

              console.log("post success = " + data.errorCode + data.errorMessage);

              if (data.status === 200) {
                   window.location = '/home/language';
              }

              // If an error, show the prompt
              if (data.errorCode === 101) {
                  $('#login-alert').show().text("Incorrect Login.");
              }

                        // res.redirect('/home/language?language=' + defaultLanguage);

          },
          error: function(data){

                alert("xhr error");

                console.log("post error = " + data.errorCode + data.errorMessage);

                console.log("error");
                console.log(data);
          },

          // Form data
          data: formdata,

          //Options to tell JQuery not to process data or worry about content-type
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false

      });
  }
```

Client-side I get an error result on the post:

```
POST https://20a09825.ngrok.com/changeProfilePicture 502 (Bad Gateway)
```

Server-side I get the following. **As you can see none of the Parse calls return an error. I can save the Parse.File object fine, set it on the user object and then save that without errors.** However, the link is broken and the even though the server logs show that I'm returning a 200 code, I'm getting that client-side error:

```
 10:53:32 web.1  | exports.changeProfilePicture -- start
10:53:33 web.1  | parseFile
10:53:33 web.1  | { _name: 'monkey_mad.jpg',
10:53:33 web.1  |   _source: 
10:53:33 web.1  |    { _resolved: true,
10:53:33 web.1  |      _rejected: false,
10:53:33 web.1  |      _resolvedCallbacks: [],
10:53:33 web.1  |      _rejectedCallbacks: [],
10:53:33 web.1  |      _result: { '0': '[object Object]', '1': 'image/jpeg' } } }
10:53:33 web.1  | file.url = function () {
10:53:33 web.1  |       return this._url;
10:53:33 web.1  |     }
10:53:33 web.1  | { _name: 'tfss-a7e96b68-37c4-4821-a54c-50dc4e848123-monkey_mad.jpg',
10:53:33 web.1  |   _source: 
10:53:33 web.1  |    { _resolved: true,
10:53:33 web.1  |      _rejected: false,
10:53:33 web.1  |      _resolvedCallbacks: [],
10:53:33 web.1  |      _rejectedCallbacks: [],
10:53:33 web.1  |      _result: { '0': '[object Object]', '1': 'image/jpeg' } },
10:53:33 web.1  |   _previousSave: 
10:53:33 web.1  |    { _resolved: true,
10:53:33 web.1  |      _rejected: false,
10:53:33 web.1  |      _resolvedCallbacks: [ [Function] ],
10:53:33 web.1  |      _rejectedCallbacks: [ [Function] ],
10:53:33 web.1  |      _result: { '0': [Circular] } },
10:53:33 web.1  |   _url: 'http://files.parsetfss.com/b4641fde-4f17-4743-bbe3-447c6c9c50c4/tfss-a7e96b68-37c4-4821-a54c-50dc4e848123-monkey_mad.jpg' }
10:53:34 web.1  | exports.changeProfilePicture -- 200
10:53:34 web.1  | POST /changeProfilePicture 200 1661ms
```

Comment: what does the parse dashboard show as dataTyp in _User.profilePic...   after '  user.set('profilePictureMedium', file);'  ?? Im not sure that u are guaranteed consistency on that column based on the code.

Comment: nothing wrong on serv-side.. guess u already kno that. Can u use curl -X POST in place of XHR in order to see more of what the client should be seeing then display that in the XHR portion of code? IMO your issue is on client around '  if(myXhr.upload)' . wild-ass-guess as to why. dont kno XHR but it looks like your code block is barfing on the InStream obj in the POST.response.

Comment: @RobertRowntree After I save it as a parseFile server-side using `var parseFile = new Parse.File(filename, {base64: file.toString('base64', 0, file.length)});`, and log out that save file, I get `_result: { '0': '[object Object]', '1': 'image/jpeg' } }` as part of the file object. So it's saving as a `jpeg` it appears... As for the Parse dashboard there isn't a way to see the file type from there.